# The continuity of $f(x,y) = \frac {\sin (xy)} {\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> I got a function:
>
> $f(x,y) = \frac {\sin (xy)}  {\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}}$ if $(x,y) \not =
>  (0,0)$, otherwise $f(x,y) = 0$,

and I should look at its continuity in $(0,0)$

- I tried the sandwich theorem but got slightly stuck unfortunately

  $ 0 \le \left|\frac {\sin (xy)}  {\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}}\right| \le 1$

I was thinking that $\sin (xy)$ is a restricted function, but not sure what to with $\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$ if $x,y$ are too small so I think my idea doesn't work. Then it would look like:

$ 0 \le \left| {\sin (xy)} \right| \le \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} = 0$

Any other idea please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have: $|\sin(xy)| \le |xy| \implies 0 \le|f(x,y)| \le \dfrac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le |x|$. Thus continuity at $(0,0)$ follows by squeeze lemma.

Comment: thanks you, but why $|x|$ is bigger than the expression on the left side?

Comment: because $\dfrac{|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le 1$

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$|sinxy|\leq xy$. Since $|x|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $|y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then

$|sinxy|\leq xy\leq x^2+y^2$

then

$|\frac{sinxy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq \frac {xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq\frac{ x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq\frac{\delta^2}{\delta}\leq \delta$

So, it is sufficiently put $\epsilon=\delta$.